# Linq statement with nullable values could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to query a SQLite database. I have 2 tables `Doctor` and `Appointment`. The `Appointment` table has 2 columns that can be null, `Date` (type `DateTime`) and `Durata` (type `TimeSpan`) which represents the duration of an appointment.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(request.Date);

var filteredDoctors = await _context.Doctors
                                    .Where(d => d.Specializare == request.Speciality)
                                    .Include(d => d.Appointments)
                                    .Where(x => x.Appointments.Any(a => (a.Date != null && a.Date.Value.Date == date.Date) &&
                    (a.Date != null &&  date >= a.Date.Value) &&
                    ((a.Date != null && a.Durata != null) && date <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(a.Date.Value, (int)a.Durata.Value.TotalMinutes))))
                        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This query works without the last "&&"

```
&& date <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(a.Date.Value, (int)a.Durata.Value.TotalMinutes)
```

The expression `a.Date.Value.Add(a.Durata.Value)` doesn't work. I tried most of the solutions found on stackoverflow, and this is the last version I came to. Is there something more that can be done to make this query work?

To simplify the query in a few words, I want select all doctors that are not busy at the specified `date`

**UPDATE**:
Error seems to appear at the `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes()` method

**UPDATE 2** :
Updated query to include `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffMinutes()`

```
var filteredDoctors = await _context.Doctors
                                    .Where(d => d.Specializare == request.Speciality)
                                    .Include(d => d.Appointments)
                                    .Where(x => !x.Appointments.Any(a => (a.Date != null && a.Date.Value.Date == date.Date) &&
                            (a.Date != null &&  date >= a.Date.Value) &&
                            (a.Date != null && a.Durata != null) && 
                            date <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(
                            a.Date.Value, System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(TimeSpan.Zero, a.Durata.Value))))
                                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What is the datatype and value of Durata? Can you provide a sample set of complete values for date, appointment.Date, and appointment.Durata for a pass and fail scenario?  There should be some way to work it out with a combination of `DiffMinutes` and `AddMinutes` or similar.

Comment: Durata has a `TimeSpan` datatype, value in this case is 1 hour, 30 minutes and 0 seconds. An example that should not return any value is if `date` is 2021-06-10 16:15:00 `appointment.Date` is 2021-06-10 16:00:00 and `appointment.Durata` is 01:00:00, because the `date` would be during an appointment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on Durata being a Timespan for the duration of the appointment the following should work:

```
date <= DbFunctions.AddMinutes(a.Date.Value, 
  DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(TimeSpan.Zero, a.Durata.Value))
```

Comment: Just tried this, now the error states that `[...] Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffMinutes' failed`.

Comment: Hmm, what version of EF are you using?  My example was using EF6 and a bit simpler, but expanding to your full example conditions and EF took exception to the use of `.Date` in the expression, no issue with `DiffMinutes`.

Comment: My installed EntityFramework version is 6.4.4

Comment: Can you update your question to add the updated expression?

Comment: I was confused why I was getting an issue with `.Date` vs. your example then realized I'm testing /w SQL Server vs. SQLLite... I suspect there is a provider limitation where SQLLite isn't parsing `DiffMinutes`. You might need to check the documentation for the SQLLite provider in relation to supported DbFunctions methods. Possibly `DiffSeconds` or `DiffMilliseconds` has been implemented where `DiffMinutes` is not? (hopefully)  A quick Google seems to indicated DbFunctions may still not be fully supported with SQLLite.  :(

Comment: According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations) TimeSpan is not supported by the db provider. Comparison and ordering don't seem to work, do you think that this might be the actual problem?

Comment: That article applies to EF Core, but I'd suspect it is provider limitations getting in the way. About the only thing I can suggest to get around that is to compose an SQL statement manually and execute that against the DbContext. I'm not sure that's easy to do /w `.Include` to load associated entities, but you should be able to compose a query to return applicable DoctorIds, then use a regular EF query to fetch the Dr. & associated Appointments by ID.